# Train brake specifics for easy/medium/hard settings in Canadian Mountain Passes (GE ES44AC)?

Tags: train-simulator-2015

This is about the train brake subsystem modeled for the *GE ES44AC* in the *Canadian Mountain Passes* [route](http://www.engine-driver.com/article/show/1296/train-simulator-route-preview-canadian-mountain-passes) for *Train Simulator 2015*.

---

Proceeding from *Field* to *Lake Louise* hauling a heavy consist uphill (1.8%), you have to make it first less than half a mile to a signal light and stop after the waypoint but obviously before the wye merge (there's a train coming in the opposite direction). Because of the consist length and hill gradient (and wanting to cover the distance at more than walking speed), I overshoot the way point and end up applying full brake very close to the merge; that is bringing both the EQ reservoir and brake pipe to 0 and having 66 (max) pressure applied to the brake cylinder. I'm looking at the next leg of the route, the other train passes and I completely release the brake (*EQ* to 90). After 60 seconds, the brake pipe has barely climbed to 3 and I still have full pressure applied to the brake.

[image]
<sup>Got it right this time over.</sup>

---

The brake subsystem has three difficulty settings (*easy*, *medium*, *hard*; using ctrl+shift+1 or 2); I have set it to *hard*. At the easiest setting, it takes some 30 seconds for the pressure to be released, maybe.

1. How long does it take for the pressure to be released from the brake
   cylinder with the hard setting?
2. What are the exact differences between the *easy/medium/hard* settings
   for the train brake subsystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [EMDSD9 loco manual](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/325951/manuals/EMDSD9_Manual_EN.pdf), the advanced braking controls adjust the **brake timing** (how long it takes for your brakes to apply/release). On *Page 7*;

- **level 1** does not simulate brake timing (so changes are nearly instantaneous, or perhaps just minimized according to your experience)
- **level 2** implements the simulation at 1/3rd of the full time.
- **level 3** is 2/3rds.
- **level 4** is full timing simulation.

This information is the same in the [U30B section of this manual](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/376932/manuals/Feather_River_Canyon_-_Oroville_to_Quincy_Manual_EN.pdf). Presumably this is the same system that's implemented in the ES44AC.

[image: BC = Brake Cylinder]

As for braking in general, I look at the **brake cylinder** number (see the BC number on the left hand side of the image) to get an idea of the actual "stopping power" being applied to the wheels. As that number gradually climbs, the train slows down more. The Dynamic Brake can also be useful for controlling your speed while the air brakes apply, although ultimately it may just take a walking pace to win the race.

Comment: Thank you ! I actually don't remember seeing your answer, sorry about that. It may be a similar system indeed, I would need to compare timings for each setting and see what gives. Since there's only 3 levels it may be you have something similar to L2-4. Thanks again !